# Excel VBA: Read 10 rows of data, run conditional loop, and Print output values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to read in values into a sub function, run a conditional loop, then print the output values in the worksheet. However, I am running into some problems. In the sub function infiltPrint I cannot seem to get the values to print in the cells.

```
Option Explicit

Dim dz() As Double
Dim WC() As Double
Dim fc() As Double
Dim NL, i As Integer

Dim sumdrain As Double
Dim infl As Double


Sub main()
    Call InfiltRead
    Call infilt
    Call Infiltprint
End Sub


Sub InfiltRead()
    Dim dz() As Double
    Dim WC() As Double
    Dim fc() As Double
    Dim NL, i As Integer
    Dim sumdrain As Double
    sumdrain = 0
    Dim infl As Double

'read inputs 
    NL = 10
    infl = Cells(2, 1)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    ReDim dz(NL)
    ReDim WC(NL)
    ReDim fc(NL)

    For i = 1 To NL
        dz(i) = Cells(1 + i, 3)
        WC(i) = Cells(1 + i, 7)
        fc(i) = Cells(1 + i, 5)
    Next i    
End Sub


Sub infilt()
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 1
    While (infl > 0) And (j <= NL)
        If infl > (fc(i) - WC(j)) * dz(j) Then
            infl = infl - (fc(i) - WC(j)) * dz(j)
            WC(j) = fc(i)
        Else
            WC(j) = WC(j) + infl / dz(j): infl = 0
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Wend
    If infl > 0 Then
        sumdrain = sumdrain + infl
        infl = 0
    End If
End Sub


Sub Infiltprint()
    Dim col As Double
    Dim rw As Double
    col = 7
    For rw = 2 To 11
        Cells(rw + 1, col).Value = WC()
    Next rw
End Sub
```

I keep getting a Type Mismatch in the line " Cells(Row + 1, col) = WC()"

I know this probably this isn't the only error in my code. Frankly, I have no clue how to print my values from the infilt sub. I attempted to use a sub main...

Comment: For one thing, you are trying to assign an array to a cell, i.e., WC() rather than WC(index) :(

Comment: how can I fix this? WC(1)? Then how to I advance to the next cell for the next WC value?

Comment: There's a better way to assign an array to a range:

Comment: Was slow in getting my edits to my last comment in: Use Cells(Row+1, col).Value = WC, with no loop. "Value" is required. May want to change the name "Row" to something else, since it is a keyword. I'm assuming that WC is still in scope.

Comment: I made all the changes to the code as you suggested, I am still getting the same type mismatch error in the same line of code

Comment: You've got multiple declarations of the same variables in different scopes. Lose the declarations of `dz`, `WC`, `fc`, `NL`, `i`, `sumdrain` and `infl` in `InfiltRead`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following version of your code will print. It changes several things noted below.

The main issue you were having was getting the WC array copied to the worksheet. You were trying to assign the whole array to individual cells.

The fix was to assign the whole WC array to the full set of cells you wanted to put it in. For this to work, WC had to be transposed. It is normally necessary to dimension WC as a Variant ("Dim WC As Variant") to assign an array to a range, and the new code reflects that.

I've also cleared out some redeclaration of variables and altered the way in which the indexing of the three arrays were done to align the lower and upper bounds of the arrays with your counters.

In the intfilt() sub, you used i as an index in a loop, but did not initialize or iterate it, and that has changed as well.

[cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/) is a well-organized and in-depth resource for VBA coding - including working with arrays. You may want to check it out.

```
  Option Explicit

  Dim dz() As Double
  Dim WC As Variant
  Dim fc() As Double
  Dim NL As Long, i As Long       '<- Integer gets converted to Long internally, so do it directly
                                  '<- Way you did it results in Variant type for i
  Dim sumdrain As Double
  Dim infl As Double

  Sub main()
     InfiltRead  <- "Call" not needed
     infilt
     Infiltprint
  End Sub

  Sub InfiltRead() 
     sumdrain = 0   '<- variables in this sub are already declared, don't redeclare
     'read inputs
     NL = 10
     infl = Cells(2, 1).Value
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' <- if processing lots of data, would want to turn off auto sheet recalculation as well
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate  
     ReDim dz(1 To NL)                    '<- set lower bound to avoid default value of 0
     ReDim WC(1 To NL)        '
     ReDim fc(1 To NL)
     For i = 1 To NL
        dz(i) = Cells(1 + i, 3).Value     '<- could assign each range directy to an array, but this ok
        WC(i) = Cells(1 + i, 7).Value
        fc(i) = Cells(1 + i, 5).Value
     Next i
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True     '<- cleanup code
  End Sub

  Sub infilt()
     Dim j As Long
     i = 1                     '<- DEBUG placeholder - you used i in this sub, but did not initialize or iterate it
     j = 1
     While (infl > 0) And (j <= NL)
        If infl > (fc(i) - WC(j)) * dz(j) Then
           infl = infl - (fc(i) - WC(j)) * dz(j)
           WC(j) = fc(i)
        Else
           WC(j) = WC(j) + infl / dz(j)
           infl = 0
        End If
        j = j + 1
        i = i + 1             '<- DEBUG placeholder iteration
     Wend
     If infl > 0 Then
        sumdrain = sumdrain + infl
        infl = 0
     End If
  End Sub

  Sub Infiltprint()
     Dim col As Long
     Dim rw As Long
     rw = 2
     col = 9                   '<- Changed from 7 to 9 for debugging (so original values would not be overwritten)
     Range(Cells(rw, col), Cells(rw + NL - 1, col)).Value = _
        Application.Transpose(WC)                   '<- needed to get proper references for assignment
  End Sub
```

Comment: The code above seems not to be printing WC(j) correctly. It is just reprinting fc(i) in column 9. ??

Comment: If you haven't already, you should work through the algebra for some of your data rows to check what you expect WC(j) to be. I tested the code on dummy parameters and data; what got printed differed depending on what these values were set to.